# How to get the default BackGround brush of a WPF button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, brush

I have a converter that converts an enumeration to a WPF brush.
So basically I return brushes depending on the provided `enum` value.

The only problem I have is to get the default brush that the system uses.

I'd like to do something like:

```
default:
    return new SolidColorBrush(Button.DefaultBackground);
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the default colors and brushes from [System.Windows.SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx).

[SystemColors.WindowBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.windowbrush.aspx) is quite likely the one you're looking for. It's the "The background color in the client area of a window."

Here's sample code on how to use the brush from code behind:

```
    private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyButton.Background = SystemColors.HighlightBrush;
    }
```

So no special tricks needed to access them.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the default color in a variable. To get the default color I would construct a new control (the type you want the default color from). After that you can use the default brush/color from this control (a new control is initialized with its default values when using the default constructor).

eg: if it is for a button you could do:

```
    static private Brush defaultButtonBackground = null;
    public Brush DefaultButtonBackground
    {
        get
        {
            if(defaultButtonBackground == null)
            {
                defaultButtonBackground = new Button().Background;
            }
            return defaultButtonBackground;
        }
    }
```

I'm not saying this is the only solution, but by implemending a property like this you only create the temporary default button once, and store its brush.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Mikaels answer was a bit faster and it worked perfectly in combination with my existing converter. But your solution would work as well, no doubt!

Comment: I had to use dummyButton = new Button(); dummyButton.BeginInit(); dummyButton.EndInit(); BackgroundColor = dummyButton.Background;

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the original question, but it might help future readers. Another option, depending on your situation, is to simply remove the background property by calling ClearValue.

```
btn.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
```